# How long should I wait between feeding my dog?

Tags: hay-day

My dog doesn't eat anything, how long should I wait?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the [Retriever](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Retriever), [Pinscher](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Pinscher), [Hound](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Hound), [Retriever Puppy](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Retriever_Puppy) or [Pinscher Puppy](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Pinscher_Puppy), you need to wait 6 hours between feeding.

> When given bacon, Pinscher puppies eat, roam the farm for **six hours**
>   and then fall asleep. Players can immediately wake them up to receive
>   35 experience points per animal.